# Why do git status and git show disagree?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-tag

Why do *git status* and *git show* disagree?

The repository is supposed to be at a tag. This is  what *git status* tells me (hash starting *609b*).

But *git show* tells me that it is at commit with hash starting *156f*.

The current situation comes doing the following to get the codebase at the tag.

```
git clean -f && git reset HEAD --hard && git fetch && \ 
git fetch --tags && git checkout daily-build-492 && git pull
```

Why the inconsistency?

Some diagnostics:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from daily-build-492
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git rev-list -n 1 daily-build-492
609b538fb0180b170170be09312fecf5a5240b6a
$ git show
commit 156f9e6b3fbfe7c16e8d821efd315428610043c2
Merge: ec154d9 15e8876
Author: ubuntu <ubuntu>
Date:   Wed Dec 2 14:09:23 2015 +0000
    Merge branch 'deploy-server'
$ git describe --tags --exact-match
fatal: no tag exactly matches '156f9e6b3fbfe7c16e8d821efd315428610043c2'
$ git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d" |grep 492
2015-11-23 07:05:18 +0000  (tag: daily-build-492)
```

Comment: (daily-build-492 == a tag, right?) You're detached from HEAD because you `git checkout <tag>`. Are you sure that you didn't want to checkout a branch? If you're checking out a tag, that means that the git index is stuck at the previous location, but the local files are checked out, based on what files look like at the tag. Another guess: if you want to stand on a specific tag, you should be able to (warning: destructive command) `git fetch --all && git reset --hard <tag>`).

Comment: @chelmertz Yes, I want exactly that "frozen" code from the tag. (This example is running a daily known build on a  server; it is not a dev environment.)

But regardless, the interesting question is why the different git commands disagree.

Comment: @torek @hoppa @chelmertz
I tried doing the above without the git pull. The  different diagnostics  I mention in IP are consistent.  I then manually did `git pull` just to see what happens. I get `Already up-to-date.` And then the diagnostics remain consistent. So, it is not clear that `git pull` "messed up" the situation. The question remains open.

Comment: That is awkward, I will try to have a better look later today

Comment: By the way, I learned that  daily-build-492 was an old tag and not the most recent as I had thought. But that should not make a difference.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce with pulling and I get the same notice you got "You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>" That makes a lot of sense since Git can not have a clue where to merge from now. The only thing I do not understand what went different for you. Can you retry the command at the top (git clean -f && git reset HEAD --hard && git fetch && \ 
git fetch --tags && git checkout daily-build-492 && git pull) and post exact output?

Comment: @hoppa Here is the output of running those commands *after* doing the command shown at the top of the OP.

  `HEAD is now at 609b538 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/dev' into dev
HEAD is now at 609b538... Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/dev' into dev
You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two keys to this and [hoppa has provided both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34046880/1256452), but let me see if I can shorten it somewhat.  (This is a challenge for me, as I tend to write very long answers. :-) )  In any case I'll try to pin a few things down more.

First, let me add here that `git pull` is just a convenience script that first runs `git fetch` for you, then—depending on your configuration and additional flags—runs either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  (The default is to do a merge, which for many users is usually the wrong thing.)

(Your question is also missing a bit of information.  Using `git pull` by itself should have produced an error.  However, if you used `git pull origin master` or similar, you should have seen some extra output from the `git pull` when it did its second step.  In any case we can see that your final state is that `HEAD` points to a merge commit, although neither of its parents appear to be the commit that your tag identifies.)

When you give it a tag,<sup>1</sup> `git checkout` puts you in "detached HEAD" state.  This sounds a bit scary, like some sort of 18th century French Revolution, but really just means that you are no longer on any branch.  Git is fine with working in this state: you can make new commits, including merges; they're just on *no* branches.  The only way to find them is by raw SHA-1, such as `156f9e6b3fbfe7c16e8d821efd315428610043c2`, or by some relative name starting from `HEAD`, such as `HEAD` itself, `HEAD~1`, `HEAD~2`, and so on.<sup>2</sup>

Having gotten into "detached HEAD" state by checking out a tag, you then made at least one more commit (really, at least two more based on the `git show` output).  These new commits are, as always with detached HEAD, on no branch at all.  The last one made was a merge, presumably from the `git merge` second-half of `git pull`.

Now `git status` shows you where your HEAD is: detached, not *at* a tag, but *from* the tag.  This means you were right at a tag (in detached HEAD state) earlier.  If you had run `git status` right then, you would have seen this:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at daily-build-492
```

Having made some new commit(s) you went to "detached from" instead of "detached at".

On the other hand, the `git show` command, as [hoppa already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34046880/1256452), shows an object.  The default object to show, if you don't name one yourself, is whatever object `HEAD` names.  In this case `HEAD` names a merge commit, so `show` displays its ID, the IDs of its parents (`Merge: ec154d9 15e8876`), the author and date, the commit message (which looks like the one `git pull` supplies to its `git merge` step), and a combined diff (empty in this case).

The somewhat curious thing is that neither parent commit matches the apparent ID of the tagged commit, `609b538fb0180b170170be09312fecf5a5240b6a`.  (I say "apparent" here because you used `git rev-list -n 1` rather than `git rev-parse daily-build-492^{commit}`, and it's possible, however unlikely, that after sorting the commits to be listed, the one that the tag actually points to is further down in the rev-list output.)  And, as I noted earlier, `git pull` with no additional arguments should just give you an error message.

(I think I failed at "shorter" :-) but perhaps at least this helps with figuring out how you got into this state.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Or indeed any commit identifier that is not the short name of a branch.  For instance, `git checkout refs/heads/master` gets you the same *commit* as `git checkout master`, but leaves you in "detached HEAD" state.  (If that's what you want, you can also use `git checkout --detach master`, which I think is more obvious.)

<sup>2</sup>If you `git checkout` something else so that `HEAD` now refers to some other commit, you're left with just the raw SHA-1, or the same with some modifier(s).  For instance `156f9e6~1` refers to the first parent of commit `156f9e6`, and `156f9e6~2` refers to that commit's first parent, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer.

When I try breaking up that long line and `git pull` separately from all the rest, I  get the message `You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details. git pull <remote> <branch>`. So, that was probably happening silently as that long line executed.

I am sure I did not edit code or do `git commit`. This is a server rather than a dev environment. So, maybe the `git pull` is to blame for "messing up" the clean tag environment. But git pull, does nothing, as mentioned, so  it's unclear why.

Comment: As you say, the somewhat curious thing is still a mismatch. I suppose that still remains unanswered.

Comment: Please see my comment under the OP.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm curious now to see what you get if you do `git rev-parse daily-build-492` and `git rev-parse daily-build-492^{commit}`.

Comment: For that first command, the output is `170a0e31d2596cc9db86138d1af3051563500ac4`

For the second (taken literally, including the word *commit*) it is  

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'daily-build-492^{commit}.': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Both the above were run *after* running the commands show in the OP.

Comment: The `.` is not part of the rev-parse argument (but the `^{commit}` is, that's the directive to gitrevisions to "peel" tags to get their target commits).  Anyway the first part tells me that the tag points to object `170a0e3...` which is definitely not `609b538...`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're being confused by two problems at once. First of all there is the fact that you're in detached HEAD state. Daily-build-492 is a Tag and you can not make changes to a Tag. If you check out a Tag while being in master (for instance) git will first give you a message like this:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

This is basically what you probably did when you executed `git checkout daily-build-492`. If you git status now you will get a message that is along these lines:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at daily-build-492
```

Afterwards you concatenated (with the &&) a pull command which gets changes in from the remote that is linked. My guess is that since this would add changes to the tag and since that is not allowed, you automatically detach from daily-build-492 into a further limbo :) The notice will now be:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from daily-build-492
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

As you can see this is exactly what your git status actually tells you after your initial commands.

Git status just shows you all difference between the index file and the **current** HEAD. This basically means all changes you've made compared to HEAD be they totally new files, changes or staged changes. Basically you're git status tells you there are no changes and you've got yourself detached from HEAD.

**Git show**

git show does something different. Git show displays information on an object. An object in git can be many things; a commit, a tag, a tree, etc. If you do not give git show an object hash behaviour seems to be to git show the last commit. This is a commit you pulled in after checking out the tag. One of the commits that got you into detached HEAD mode to begin with.

**Simple reproduction of your issue**

```
git init test.git
cd test.git
touch A
git add A
git commit -m "A, jay"
touch B
git add B
git commit -m "B, jay"
git tag TAG-1
git checkout TAG-1 //Now you will get the notice about git detached HEAD etc
git status // result below
//HEAD detached at TAG-1
//nothing to commit, working directory clean
touch C
git add C
git commit -m "C, shoopdawhoop" // a warning like below is outputted,but it works
//[detached HEAD eda8080] C
// 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
// create mode 100644 C
git status // output below again
// HEAD detached from TAG-1
// nothing to commit, working directory clean
git show // will now tell us about commit C the last one we added.
// commit eda808088594ae7b05ae1b57ffd95f7f810a9091
// Author: a@example.net <a@example.net>
```

This small set of commands basically mimics what I think you have done. Maybe the && concatenation of commands silenced output, maybe it didn't but you didn't post. The moral of the story here is that you tried to do something that git does not allows.

As you can see in the example this explains why your `git describe --tags` does not result in anything since you give it the hash of commit C (not really, but it is analogous to commit C in my example.)

Your `git rev-list` does give you what you expect since you specifically ask it for the last commit in daily-build-492.

Comment: Thank you, @hoppa for the answer and the reconstruction.

However, I did not edit the code at this repository or commit at all, since it was at a tag. This is on a server, not a dev branch.

As to the  `&& git pull` after checking out the tag, you mentioned that "My guess is that since this would add changes to the tag and since that is not allowed, you automatically detach from daily-build-492 into a further limbo."


But it seems that `git pull` does not even work when you do it on a tag, so that still doesn't explain the mismatch between `git show` and `git status` as in the example I gave.

Comment: If I do `git pull` after checking out the branch I get:
`You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.
    git pull <remote> <branch>`

So, that is not what caused the mismatch.

Comment: Please see my comment under the OP.